# Radio buttons does not show checked state when styled with Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When I just use a plain group of radio buttons with Bootstrap like this with no special styling then it works just fine:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="radio">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label><input type="radio" value="keep">Ändra inte lösenordet</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><input type="radio" value="auto">Generera ett nytt lösenord automatiskt</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><input type="radio" value="manual">Ange ett nytt lösenord manuellt</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" class="custom-control-input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ange ett lösenord manuellt">
        </div>
                   
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The radio buttons are showing the checked state when clicked upon. But if I try to style the buttons using the `custom-control` CSS class like this:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="radio custom-control custom-radio">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="custom-control-label"><input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="keep">Ändra inte lösenordet</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="custom-control-label"><input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="auto">Generera ett nytt lösenord automatiskt</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="custom-control-label"><input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="manual">Ange ett nytt lösenord manuellt</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" class="custom-control-input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ange ett lösenord manuellt">
        </div>
                       
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

... it does not work. Nothing happens when I click on the buttons. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your css?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4 standard styling, no extra CSS. The radio buttons are showing the style but not the checked state.

Comment: Custom radio button solutions depend on a specific DOM structure regarding label and input where the input needs to come *before* the label, with the label being a sibling. This is due to limitations of CSS.

Comment: It **does work technically**, it's just given your current HTML structure CSS cannot show that the radio button is checked so it doesn't work * visually*. Please check my answer and explanations below and comment if anything remains unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom radio (and checkbox, too) button solutions depend on a specific DOM structure regarding `label` and `input` where the `input` needs to come *before* the `label`, with the `label` being a sibling (most often realized with the expectation of the `label` being an *adjacent* sibling). This is due to limitations of CSS.

That means your labels are no longer associated with the radio button because it's no longer wrapping it. To fix that,  give the radio buttons an `id` and add the `for=""` attribute on the label containing that same `id`).

Also, your radio buttons need to share a common `name`, otherwise all radio buttons can be checked at the same time.

So to fix it, make changes according to that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="radio custom-control custom-radio">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="i" value="keep" id="i1" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="i1">Ändra inte lösenordet</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="auto" name="i" id="i2" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="i2">Generera ett nytt lösenord automatiskt</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="i" value="manual" id="i3" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="i3">Ange ett nytt lösenord manuellt</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" class="custom-control-input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ange ett lösenord manuellt">
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked straight away. And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: But it's almost invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Working now. You just needed to add a `id="customRadio"` in your input and in your labels a `for="customRadio"`.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="radio custom-control custom-radio">

        <div class="form-group">
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="customRadio"><label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio">Ändra inte lösenordet</label>
     </div>
     
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" class="custom-control-input" value="auto"><label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Generera ett nytt lösenord automatiskt</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" class="custom-control-input" value="manual" > <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Ange ett nytt lösenord manuellt</label>
        </div>
        

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" class="custom-control-input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ange ett lösenord manuellt">
        </div>
        
            
    </div>
```